# How to read in a user's input in shell script and replace a line with the input after the script finishes executing?

Tags: sed, editors

I currently have a script that asks for users to verify their OAuth credentials, which then returns a refresh token. It is annoying for the user to have to place the refresh token in themselves. I would like for there to be a way to automatically edit the file and to place a refresh token if one doesn't exist. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
REFRESH_TOKEN=
if [ -z "$REFRESH_TOKEN" ]; then
   (opens a webpage for the user to authenticate themselves)
   (we then pull the refresh token programmatically and set it)
   REFRESH_TOKEN=$(some api call)
fi
```

If a user runs this with the `REFRESH_TOKEN` variable empty, is there a way to update the second line either in real time or after execution? I have tried `sed` but it doesn't work as the  `REFRESH_TOKEN=$(some api call)` also gets affected.

Comment: The `if-then` will always execute since the refresh token is hardcoded to empty in 2nd line. So you could just as well write: `REFRESH_TOKEN=$(some api call)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, `sed` should work as long as you add `^` and `$` surrounding the regular expression. For example

`sed 's/^REFRESH_TOKEN=$/REFRESH_TOKEN={token}/g'` would work, because it will only match `REFRESH_TOKEN=` if it's the only thing on the line, the `REFRESH_TOKEN=$(some api call)` section shouldn't be affected because of the contents after the `=`

You could also use limit the scope of sed by doing something like
`sed '2 s/REFRESH_TOKEN=/REFRESH_TOKEN={token}/g'`, but this is only a good solution if you are *certain* that the line you need to substitute is always going to be line number 2

Answer (score 2):

```
  REFRESH_TOKEN=$(some api call)
  sed '2 s/^REFRESH_TOKEN=.*/REFRESH_TOKEN='"$REFRESH_TOKEN/" -i "$0"
```

Here sed is specifically told to only modify line 2 of the script

or instead of the 2 you could use a range using line numbers:

`sed '1,5 s/`...

or a pattern

`sed '1,/^#END-OF-SETTINGS-MARKER#/ s/`...

Answer (score 0):

The following line encapsulates the logic of the bash script:

```
: ${REFRESH_TOKEN:="$(some api call)"}
```

What it does is initialize the refresh token variable only if has not been done so before. The initial value is taken by running the web api call.

Read up on the `bash parameter substitutions` in the bash manual for further info.